# Error trying to execute sql from inside SQL CLR

Tags: sqlclr

I have the following code:

```
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static int GetInt()
    {
        int retValue = 0;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection = true"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select MyInt from SomeTable";
            object timeOut = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // <- error happen here

        }
        return retValue;

    }
```

I get the following exception in

```
cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

> {"This statement has attempted to access data whose access is restricted by the assembly."}

Comment: this is not an issue anymore, I resolved it !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed to add DataAccess = DataAccess.Read to the function attribute in order to do that.

Answer (score 10):

As a side note, if you're trying to access temporary tables created with `#`, such as `#tmp`, you need to also put in `SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccess.Read`. Another way around this would be to use a common table expression to get your data.